# What is the effect of MOVE SPACES TO [TABLE]

Tags: vb.net, cobol, transcription

I'm transcribing some COBOL to VB.Net, but do not have access to a mainframe or COBOL compiler. In several places in the program I'm transcribing, there is a `MOVE SPACES TO` statement where the target is a table identifier with no index. Does this clear all records in the table, or just the 'current' record pointed to by the specified index variable?

**Table declaration:**

```
05 WS-EDI-HOLD-TABLE.                       
   10 WS-EDI-HOLD-TBL OCCURS 1000 TIMES     
                       INDEXED BY IDX1-EDI  
                                  IDX2-EDI. 
      15 WS-EDI-HOLD-DATA     PIC X(269).
```

**MOVE SPACES TO statement:** (Appears several places)

```
MOVE SPACES TO WS-EDI-HOLD-TABLE
```

Comment: From what I remember it will clear the whole table.

Comment: "where the target is a table identifier with no index", I guess that is a typo, should be "with an index"?

Comment: @BillWoodger Not, that's not a typo. My point was that **no** index was specified in the `MOVE SPACES TO` statement. The much more common situation is when there **is** an index, in which case the statement clearly just sets that particular row to spaces. For example: `MOVE SPACES TO WS-EDI-HOLD-TABLE (IDX1-EDI)`

Comment: No. You can try that, but it will give you a compile error. In this case it is only WS-EDI-HOLD-TBL (a cunning name) and items subordinate to it which can be subscripted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You end up setting the entire table to `SPACES` with:

```
 MOVE SPACES TO WS-EDI-HOLD-TABLE
```

That would be all 269000 bytes that comprize this table will now contain spaces

Any `MOVE SPACES TO data-item` type statement implicitly references all lower level data items as well. Beware that this type of reference assumes `PICTURE X` data. This can lead to real trouble when a lower level data item has an explicit PICTURE that is not compatible with 'X' type data, as is the case with COMP-3 fields for example.